# Cannot install anything in command prompt

Tags: command-line, software-installation

I was trying to install pcl library like this : `sudo apt install libpcl-dev`. sudo apt-get -f install this command wasnot running too I tried install something couple of days back it did not work either

Tried googling and tried some solutions but still nothing (even some of the solutions did not work):

```
'Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 622 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up qgis-providers (3.10.5+dfsg-1~bionic1) ...
free(): invalid pointer
Aborted (core dumped)
dpkg: error processing package qgis-providers (--configure):
 installed qgis-providers package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 134
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-qgis:
 python3-qgis depends on qgis-providers (= 3.10.5+dfsg-1~bionic1); however:
  Package qgis-providers is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-qgis (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
         Errors were encountered while processing:
 qgis-providers
    python3-qgis
    E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)'
```

Any helps would be great

Comment: Is this only when you try to install `libpcl-dev` or does it happen with all packages like you say in the question title?

Comment: sudo apt-get -f install
this command wasnot running too I tried install something couple of days back it did not work either

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add this. Make sure to include the errors you get from installing another package. Are they always the same?

Comment: This is what I am getting when install pcl:
``` Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libpcl-dev is already the newest version (1.8.1+dfsg1-2ubuntu2.18.04.1).
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3.9 : Depends: libpython3.9-stdlib (= 3.9.16-1+bionic1) but 3.9.1-1+bionic1 is to be installed

E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution). ```